# JSDoc Comment Folding In VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments, jsdoc

Is there a way to fold JSDoc-style comment blocks in VSCode v1.25 for JavaScript files? I get normal code collapse offered, but comment blocks seem excluded. Is there a keyboard shortcut that would collapse code even without the GUI handlebars showing?

[image]

Answer (score 36):

I had the same issue, and fixed it by doing this:

Go to `File` -> `Preferences` -> `Settings` and change the following entry from `auto` to `indentation`

```
"editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation"
```

Now JSDoc comments are folding as expected, hope this works for you as well!

Answer (score 6):

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+/",
  "command": "editor.foldAllBlockComments",
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

will fold block comments, like jsdoc.  But I don't see a command for specifically unfolding (all or just) )block comments.  But you can use:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+]",
  "command": "editor.unfold",
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

o do that when cursor is on that line of folded jsdoc comment.