# VSCode indent in Swagger JSDoc

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, swagger, jsdoc, openapi

I'm using [swagger-jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-jsdoc) with Express. Using this lib to describe an api end-point I use following lines in JSDock block in YAML:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /users:
 *    post:
 *      summary: Register a user
 *      tags: [Users]
 *      description: Register a new user and return its cookie token (connect.sid)
 *      parameters:
 *        - in: body
 *          name: body
 *          schema:
 *            type: object
 *            required: [login, password, confirm]
 *            description: user's credential
 *            properties:
 *              login:
 *                type: string
 *                minLength: 3
 *                maxLength: 10
 *              email:
 *                type: string
 *              password:
 *                type: string
 *                minLength: 6
 *              confirm:
 *                type: string
 *      responses:
 *        200:
 *          description: OK
 *          schema:
 *            $ref: '#/components/schemas/AuthState'
 *        422:
 *          $ref: '#/components/responses/UnprocessableEntity'
 */

router.post('/', usersController.register);
```

But the problem is that VSCode completely ignores indentation when I put a new line, it also doesn't show the level of indentation which makes it really difficult to make specification as every single new line I have to press [tab] to reach needed indentation level. Extensions like rainbow indents don't work either because they orient on vscode indents.

Are there any settings or extensions I could use to work with this? 
Or maybe I'm using a wrong approach and there are better and more used approaches to work with this with Express? Would like to hear about these as well

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413448/ to enable jsdoc comment folding in vscode. I found that useful, hth a bit.

Comment: @DarkZ have you found a better solution to this? I am facing the same problems right now ...

Comment: @user3740359 no luck here...

Comment: Same problem. Tired of manually adding spaces

Comment: FWIW I found it simpler to work with JSON in there, then the spaces are one less headache.

Comment: @Mendhak could you elaborate a little bit more, please? I'm not sure `swagger-jsdoc` allows `json` in `jsdoc`

Comment: @DarkZ I've created an example gist here: https://gist.github.com/mendhak/64189150b80a4e52cc88439c5318a17e  Try generating your OpenAPI with that, both should work (I use the JSON way for everything)

Comment: @Mendhak tried this and it worked just fine. If I remove the leading asterisk in a jsdoc it will also save indentation level apparently while still compiling just nice. This is what I needed for VSCode, maybe other code editors / IDE keep indentation level even with leading asterisks

Comment: @Mendhak btw, could you write your recommendation as an answer to this question so I could set it as the best answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello for what it's worth I avoid the YAML-indentation-complaining problem by writing the OpenAPI bits with JSON in jsdoc.  The swagger-jsdoc package works with JSON in jsdoc comments.

In the first example I've written normal JSON, which VSCode indents, and after that I've used column select to put the `*` in front of each line

```js
/**
 * @openapi
 * "/abc": {
 *      "get": {
 *         "description": "Welcome to swagger-jsdoc!",
 *         "responses": {
 *            "200": {
 *               "description": "Returns a mysterious string.",
 *               "content": {
 *                  "text/xml": {
 *                      "schema": {
 *                          "$ref": "#/components/schemas/MyResponse"
 *                        }
 *                     }
 *                  }
 *            }
 *         }
 *      }
 *   }
 */
 app.get('/abc', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});
```

In the second example I'm able to get JSON indents by only having the `*` go up to the `get` method. When writing JSON after that, VSCode gives me indents.

```js
/**
 * @openapi
 * "/123": {
 *      "get": {
            "description": "My numeric endpoint",
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "Returns a mysterious number",
                    "content": {
                        "application/json": {
                           "$ref": "#/components/schemas/NumResponse"
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
 */
app.get('/123', (req, res) => {
    res.send(123);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I created [a simple extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ajmnz.swagger-jsdoc-indent) that targets this particular issue when writing YAML specs with `swagger-jsdoc`.

Everything is documented in the README, but basically you write your spec like this (which allows for automatic indentation)

```
/**
 * Spec for the route /auth/register.
 *
@openapi
/auth/register:
  post:
    summary: Register as user
    tags:
      - Auth
    requestBody:
      required: true
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: object
            required:
              - name
              - email
              - password
            properties:
              name:
                type: string
              email:
                type: string
                format: email
                description: Must be unique
              password:
                type: string
                format: password
                minLength: 8
                description: At least one number and one letter
 * 
 * More regular comments here
 */
router.post("/auth/register", authMiddleware.validate, authController.register);
```

Select your comment block, press `cmd + shift + P` (MacOS) or `ctrl + shift + P` (Windows) and search for `Format swagger-jsdoc comment`.

The extension will:

- Run [prettier](https://prettier.io/) to fix/catch indentation errors
- Add an asterisk at the start of each line
- Replace your comment block with the formatted one
- Respect any indentation of your block

```
/**
 * Spec for the route /auth/register.
 *
 * @openapi
 * /auth/register:
 *   post:
 *     summary: Register as user
 *     tags:
 *       - Auth
 *     requestBody:
 *       required: true
 *       content:
 *         application/json:
 *           schema:
 *             type: object
 *             required:
 *               - name
 *               - email
 *               - password
 *             properties:
 *               name:
 *                 type: string
 *               email:
 *                 type: string
 *                 format: email
 *                 description: Must be unique
 *               password:
 *                 type: string
 *                 format: password
 *                 minLength: 8
 *                 description: At least one number and one letter
 *
 *
 * More regular comments here
 */
router.post("/auth/register", authMiddleware.validate, authController.register);
```

Comment: is there any way you can format with the astericks there already?

Comment: @DucksEatTurtles Kind of. We released a feature on the latest version that lets you remove the asterisks automatically, edit the spec and then add them back again. You can read more in the [Readme](https://github.com/ajmnz/swagger-jsdoc-indent#unformatting)

Comment: yup that'll do it